# Multiple Objects in Foreach Loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following two foreach loops that are working for me:

```
foreach ( $pa_speciesreactivityabbrs as $pa_speciesreactivityabbr ) {
echo '<span>' .$pa_speciesreactivityabbr->name. '</span>';
}

foreach ( $pa_speciesreactivitys as $pa_speciesreactivity ) {
echo '<span>' .$pa_speciesreactivity->name. '</span>';
}
```

However I need to combine the $pa_speciesreactivityabbrs and $pa_speciesreactivitys in the same loop to output $pa_speciesreactivityabbr->name and $pa_speciesreactivity->name together.

I have gone through a number SO answers from other posts, but can't seem to apply them to my situation.

Comment: At the time of putting your values in the object why don't you use single one. in an object any number of data can store of any format? that's only the solution. Other wise you have to use two foreach loop.

Comment: I'm using WordPress and both data sets are coming from separate [get_the_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) , so I am not sure if, or how I would combine the two.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your objects are in normal arrays. Assuming you don't use associative arrays, you could do this easily by looping through one of them and output data from both at the same time. Like this:

```
foreach ($array1 as $index => $obj1) {
    echo '<span>' . $obj1->name . $array2[$index]->name . '</span>';
}
```

I shortened the array names to make it more readable, but I'm sure you see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  You suggestions is similar to something I had tried previously, but didn't seem to work for me.  This is my version of your example code

 `foreach ($pa_speciesreactivityabbrs as $index => $obj1) {
    echo '<span>' . $obj1->name . $pa_speciesreactivitys[$index]->name . '</span>';
}`